# reset the content without reloading page p5

Tags: p5.js

I am making my own version of minesweeper using p5.

Right now, when I click on the bomb cell, I show all the bombs in the given grid.. but the game is still playable. Is there any way to restart the game without reloading the page?

I can produce an alert but that does not do much except say that "game is over", is there any way to restart when I click on OK on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd want to store the state of your game in some sketch-level variables. Then to reset the game, you'd want to set the variables back to their original values. You might do this in something like a `reset()` function. Here's a simple example:

```
var y;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
    reset();
}

function reset(){
    y = 0;
}

function mousePressed(){
    reset();
}

function draw() {
  background(220);

    ellipse(width/2, y, 20, 20);

    y++;
}
```

In your case, you'd probably want to call the `reset()` function after the user presses the okay button in the dialog.